# Display images from List<T> to flowLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, list, wia

I'm struggling with displaying images from the list of images into flowLayoutPanel. Actually, I'm building a scanning application which scans documents from feeder or flatbed. When it scans document from feeder it displays the first scanned document into front pictureBox and other ones into a list. I am able to display only the first one in panel and the other pictures behave like they are not even there.
Here is the code sample:

```
// Perform scanning
                List<Image> images = this.ScannerDevice.PerformScan().ToList();

                // Show picture in window
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    this.FrontImage = images[0];
                    this.BackImage = (images.Count > 1) ? images[1] : null;

                    this.SetDuplexDisplayOrientation();

                    this.splitContainer.Panel2Collapsed = (this.BackImage == null);
                    this.panelProgress.Visible = false;                       

                    foreach (Image image in images)
                    {
                        PictureBox pf = new PictureBox();
                        pf.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
                        pf.Height = 150;
                        pf.Width = 170;
                        pf.Image = pictureBoxFront.Image;
                        pf.Click += new EventHandler(picture_click_scanned);
                        flowLayoutPanel2.Controls.Add(pf);
                    }

                    ScanFinishedEventArgs eventArgs = new ScanFinishedEventArgs { AcceptScan = true };
                    if (this.ScanFinished != null)
                        this.ScanFinished(this, eventArgs);
                    this.buttonOK.Enabled = eventArgs.AcceptScan;
                });
            }
            catch (COMException ex)
            {
                string message = WiaException.GetMessageFromComException(ex);
                MessageBox.Show(message, "Greška u skeniranju", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Greška", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            // UI to the Ready-to-Save or Retry mode
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                this.UseWaitCursor = false;
                this.buttonRetry.Enabled = true;
                this.button3.Enabled = true;
                this.trackBarThreshold.Enabled = true;
                this.panelProgress.Visible = false;
            });

        }) { IsBackground = true }.Start();
    }
```

Also:

```
public Image FrontImage
    {
        get { return this.pictureBoxFront.Image; }
        private set { this.pictureBoxFront.Image = value; }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns the scanned, but possibly post-processed image of the back (if duplex scan)
    /// </summary>
    public Image BackImage
    {
        get { return this.pictureBoxBack.Image; }
        private set { this.pictureBoxBack.Image = value; }
    }
```

Comment: `pf.Image = pictureBoxFront.Image;` here only you are adding front image. Where you adding your other pictures?

Comment: I tried pictureBoxBack also through new loop and also in that one and nothing. It behaves like there are no back pictures at all

Comment: Do you have all the pictures in this loop?? `foreach (Image image in images)`

Comment: List<Image> images = this.ScannerDevice.PerformScan().ToList();  There they are. All of them are here and through this one here: // Show picture in window
                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    this.FrontImage = images[0];
                    this.BackImage = (images.Count > 1) ? images[1] : null;  It shows the front one and the other ones are hidden.

Comment: I'm guessing that your front image is working because of this code. `this.FrontImage = images[0];` what you have to do is get other images and add them to the controller.

Comment: I also believe that thats the problem but i don't know how to differ front and back if I make all of them display in front picturebox. Some exception will occur definetly

Comment: try with this change.. `pf.Image = image;`

Comment: Ahh... again only the first one. Now i'm suspecting that those others are lost somewhere during the scan.

Comment: Do yu think that problem is here: this.BackImage = (images.Count > 1) ? images[1] : null; What is the option for me

Comment: I think you need to change backImage property to. `public List<Image> BackImage`

Comment: This is a library for WIA I found on the internet and put in my project. Here this back image is maybe only for duplex scan. I really don't know where my other pictures go.

Comment: No It does not work :(. I believe that only the first one is meant to go to front picturebox and if duplex scan accours the other page goes on the back. If that happens this splitcontainer just puts those two pictureboxes next to each other and if duplex doe't occurs it just puts front image in the middle. I have to make that all other scanned papers appear in the picture front just before they are sent to flowLayoutPanel so the next scanned document can be displayed in front picturebox